# What am i doing wrong? i have tried to manipulate the arrays to capitalize each word, count but i just get the raw list to be displayed

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, counter, capitalization

Displays the list of names (last name followed by a comma, followed by one space, followed by first name) that are read from the input file in ascending order. Each first name and last name must be capitalized (first letter in upper case and the remaining letters in lower case). First and last names must be lined up as per the example below.

For each first name in the file, displays the number of times that the first name appears in the file. (i.e. firstName: count).

For each last name in the file, displays the number of times that the last name appears in the file. (i.e. lastName: count).

For each name in the file, (last name followed by a comma, followed by one space, followed by first name) displays the number of times that the names appears in the file. (i.e. name: count).

Displays the list of unique names

Writes the list of unique names

The output should be:

```
 Enter the name of the input file

 input.txt

 ******* All Names *********
 Beres, Kirsten
 Beres, Kirsten
 Beumer, Gretta
 Hutt, Colette
 Hutt, Shawanda
 Jones, Colette
 Jones, Marcia
 Koenig, Gerri
 Means, Tijuana
 Montilla, Adriana
 Montilla, Adriana
 Montilla, Adriana
 Montilla, Adriana
 Mossman, Emmanuel
 Sapienza, Colette
 Sapienza, Colette
 Shover, Neva
 Stanfill, Marcia

 ******* First Names count*********
 Adriana 4
 Colette 4
 Emmanuel 1
 Gerri 1
 Gretta 1
 Kirsten 2
 Marcia 2
 Neva 1
 Shawanda 1
 Tijuana 1
 ******* Last Names count *********
 Beres 2
 Beumer 1
 Hutt 2
 Jones 2
 Koenig 1
 Means 1
 Montilla 4
 Mossman 1
 Sapienza 2
 Shover 1
 Stanfill 1
 ******* All Names count*********
 Beres, Kirsten 2
 Beumer, Gretta 1
 Hutt, Colette 1
 Hutt, Shawanda 1
 Jones, Colette 1
 Jones, Marcia 1
 Koenig, Gerri 1
 Means, Tijuana 1
 Montilla, Adriana 4
 Mossman, Emmanuel 1
 Sapienza, Colette 2
 Shover, Neva 1
 Stanfill, Marcia 1
 ******* All Unique Names *********
 Beres, Kirsten
 Beumer, Gretta
 Hutt, Colette
 Hutt, Shawanda
 Jones, Colette
 Jones, Marcia
 Koenig, Gerri
 Means, Tijuana
 Montilla, Adriana
 Mossman, Emmanuel
 Sapienza, Colette
 Shover, Neva
 Stanfill, Marcia

 Enter the name of the output file
 output.txt
```

This is what I have so far but I feel lost, cannot find a way to correctly capitalize and count then display it. what am i doing wrong?

```
public static void getNames(ArrayList<String> fn,
                            ArrayList<String> ln) throws IOException {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("What is the name input file? ");

    String fileName = kb.next();

    File inpFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inpFile);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = in.next();
        String lastName = in.next();
        fn.add(firstName);
        ln.add(lastName);
    }
}

public static void display(ArrayList<String> names) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {

        System.out.println(names.get(i));
    }
}

public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> firstName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < firstName.size(); i++) {
        firstName.set(i; toCapital(firstName.get(i)));
    }
}
 /*
 * public static void capitalize(ArrayList<String> names) {
 * for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++){
 * names.set(i,toCapital(names.get(i)));
 * }
 * }
 */
//public static String toCapital (String name){
//String.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) +

//String.toLowerCase(name.substring(1));

//return j;
//}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<>();
    getNames(first, last);
    //display(first);
    //display(last);
    ArrayList<String> allNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++) {
        allNames.add(last.get(i) + ", " + first.get(i));
    }

    display(allNames);
}
```

This is the content of the input file:

```
colette Sapienza
gretta Beumer
EMManuel Mossman
Colette Sapienza
marcia Jones
Shawanda Hutt
Adriana monTILla
adriana montilla
Adriana Montilla
Colette Jones
Colette Hutt
Marcia Stanfill
NeVa shover
tijuana Means
Adriana Montilla
gerri KoeNig
Kirsten beres
Kirsten Beres
```

Comment: If you want help, then please write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), show what you have tried, and ask a single question. Example: One SO question could be "I have written this method to capitalize a string, but it's not working, because....". Another SO question could be, "I don't know how to count number of times each word appears in this list." --- Hint: Both a those much smaller questions are very likely already answered, so try searching.... --- This is of course assuming that I understood what your question was, there's **so much text**.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you can see, you need to put some strings in lower case aswell - unless its a typo, you have monTILla, so you should need some method to lower case something like for loop and inside: `lastName.set(i,lastName.get(i).substring(1,lastName.get(i).length().toLowerCase()));`

Other than that, you have to have capitalizer method for last name aswell, and run both in the main method.

Then for counting, use a HashMap in order to make your life easier.

Comment: `toLowerCase` is  a method not a property

Comment: ye its typo i wasnt typing in IDE.

Comment: thanks, i am trying to re write the whole code because i think i am not properly placing the for loops correctly

Answer (score 1):

Iam not providing code. But i will explain what to do.

```
First lowercase all the names before processing.

Split the name with space as delimeter(Or whatever you may need). So you 
get a String[] for each name. where index 0 points to firstname and 1
points to lastname. Add the firstname to hashmap as key and value is the 
count of them. Dont forget to update the count if it already exists.

Atlast you will have a hashmap with all firstname with their counts and 
another map with lastname and counts. You can count unique names where 
we split the string in to arrays and do the same.`
```

Comment: thanks, i am new to java and really confused with everything, but i appreciate your explanation.